# Android 3.0.1 Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :app2

Tags: android, gradle, import, migrate

I imported the project 'forecastie-master-master' from GitHub to my own project. I followed the steps for importing a project. Please help me with this error, I am new to importing projects.

my own project's gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bumbleshet.tourpinas3"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    // implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
    //imlementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    //implementatoin 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    // implementation 'com.google.android.gms.play-servies:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.lapism:searchview:4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.8.0'

    //implementation project (':app2')//{
       // exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'library'
    //}
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation project(':app2')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'



my imported project's gradle:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "cz.martykan.forecastie"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds true
        abortOnError false
        xmlReport true
        htmlReport true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.android.apps.dashclock:dashclock-api:+'
    implementation 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.4.0.1'
    implementation 'com.diogobernardino:williamchart:2.2'
}
```

settings.gradle:

```
include ':app2',':app'
```

errors:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :app2. <a href="openFile:C:../build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="Unable to resolve dependency for ":app@debug/compileClasspath": Could not resolve project :app2.">

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :app2. <a href="openFile:C:../build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="Unable to resolve dependency for ":app@debug/compileClasspath": Could not resolve project :app2.">

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :app2. <a href="openFile:C:../build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="Unable to resolve dependency for ":app@debug/compileClasspath": Could not resolve project :app2.">

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :app2. <a href="openFile:C:../build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="Unable to resolve dependency for ":app@debug/compileClasspath": Could not resolve project :app2.">

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :app2. <a href="openFile:C:../build.gradle">Open File</a><br><a href="Unable to resolve dependency for ":app@debug/compileClasspath": Could not resolve project :app2.">
```

details:

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :app2. Could not resolve project :app2.
```

Required by: project :app

> Unable to find a matching configuration of project :app2:
>        - Configuration 'debugApiElements':
>            - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
>            - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found incompatible value 'Apk'.
>            - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
>            - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
>        - Configuration 'debugMetadataElements':
>            - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
>            - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found incompatible value 'Metadata'.
>            - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
>            - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' but no value provided.
>        - Configuration 'debugRuntimeElements':
>            - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found compatible value 'debug'.
>            - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found incompatible value 'Apk'.
>            - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'debug' but wasn't required.
>            - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' and found incompatible value 'java-runtime'.
>        - Configuration 'profileApiElements':
>            - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found incompatible value 'profile'.
>            - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found incompatible value 'Apk'.
>            - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'profile' but wasn't required.
>            - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
>        - Configuration 'profileMetadataElements':
>            - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found incompatible value 'profile'.
>            - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found incompatible value 'Metadata'.
>            - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'profile' but wasn't required.
>            - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' but no value provided.
>        - Configuration 'profileRuntimeElements':
>            - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found incompatible value 'profile'.
>            - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found incompatible value 'Apk'.
>            - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'profile' but wasn't required.
>            - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' and found incompatible value 'java-runtime'.
>        - Configuration 'releaseApiElements':
>            - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found incompatible value 'release'.
>            - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found incompatible value 'Apk'.
>            - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
>            - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' and found compatible value 'java-api'.
>        - Configuration 'releaseMetadataElements':
>            - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found incompatible value 'release'.
>            - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found incompatible value 'Metadata'.
>            - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
>            - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' but no value provided.
>        - Configuration 'releaseRuntimeElements':
>            - Required com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' and found incompatible value 'release'.
>            - Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found incompatible value 'Apk'.
>            - Found com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.VariantAttr 'release' but wasn't required.
>            - Required org.gradle.api.attributes.Usage 'java-api' and found incompatible value 'java-runtime'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot import an 'Apk' as a module into an application.  It needs to be an 'Aar'.

The error:

```
Required com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.AndroidTypeAttr 'Aar' and found incompatible value 'Apk'
```

usually means you need to change the module's build.gradle from

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

to

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```